# How to ignore files starting with `flycheck_` on `find-name-dired`?

Tags: find-dired

During my search I keep having an error as follows:

`Search failed with status 1: find: ‘/home/user/folder/flycheck_Driver.py’: No such file or directory`

**[Q]** Is there any way to ignore files as following regex: `flycheck_*.py`?

---

My setup:

```
(defun my-find-orgfiles ()
  (interactive)
  (setq toggle-case-fold-search 0)  ; Turn Off Smart Case Sensitivity
  (find-name-dired "~/folder" "*py"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'my-find-orgfiles)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")))
```

Than, `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then I use `Q` to use `query-replace on the marked files`. And enter `.value` to replace with `value`.

**=>** Better solution could be to let `emacs` [create `flycheck_` files in another folder](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/58935/18414)?

=> Should I use `dired-omit-files` as [from the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14850863/2402577).

Comment: Is the question about `query-replace`, as the title says? If not, please correct the title.

Comment: @Drew I updated the title. I think when I toggle all files `flycheck_*.py` also included as well, which leads query replacement to fail, since flycheck files are remove right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem as follows, with following:

`find-dired "~/eBlocBroker" "-name \\*.py ! -name flycheck_\\*.py)`

---

```
(defun my-find-orgfiles ()
  (interactive)
  (find-dired "~/folder" "-name \\*.py ! -name flycheck_\\*.py ! -name __init__.py"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'my-find-orgfiles)
```

---

Please note that comments on this answer in [How to get Dired to ignore files with specific extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14850863/2402577)
helped me to solve it.